# Would a flat or tree-like file structure allow for faster fetching of files by Path?

Tags: filesystems, database, ntfs, file-server, database-performance

Would a flat file structure allow for faster locating/fetching of files by Path in an NTFS (Windows 10 File System) or would it essentially be as efficient as a highly structured tree with a bunch of subfolders? I'm using node.js to fetch a few hundred million locally stored JSON files and I'd prefer a tree-like file structure, but I want to make sure that wouldn't be less efficient than a flatter file structure and less depth/nested folders.

Comment: An NTFS volume with several hundred million files in a single folder would be unusable.  Of course you could test this yourself by using a script to create a large number of files and test the performance at checkpoints.